# Grunt task not creating dist folders when executes

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, gruntjs

I have a grunt task that I'm using to concatenate & minify files. It's using the usemin package and works up to the point of creating a .tmp folder with all of the files concatentated but falls short of creating the dist folder and move the scripts into it. Not sure what I'm missing in the script to create the 'dis' folder at runtime. Any assistance is appreciated.

```
 'use strict';
 var mountFolder = function (connect, dir) {
return connect.static(require('path').resolve(dir));
 };

 module.exports = function (grunt) {

require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

var projectConfig = {
    app: ['./'],
    dist: 'dist'
};

grunt.log.write(projectConfig.app);

grunt.initConfig({
    project: projectConfig,

    clean: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                dot: true,
                src: [
                    '.tmp',
                    '<%= project.dist %>/*',
                    '!<%= project.dist %>/.git*'
                ]
            }]
        },
    },

    useminPrepare: {
        html: '<%= project.app %>/app.html',
        options: {
            dest: '<%= project.dist %>',
            uglify: 'uglify'
        }
    },

    usemin: {
        html: '<%= project.app %>/app.html',
        css: ['<%= project.dist %>/**/*.css'],
        options: {
            dest: '<%= project.dist %>',
            assetDirs: '.tmp',
            basedir: '<%= project.app %>'
        }
    },
    copy: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= project.dist %>',
                dest: '<%= project.dist %>',
                src: [
                    '*.{ico,txt,png}',
                    '.htaccess',
                    'lib*//***/*//*',
                    'img/{,*//*}*.{gif,webp}',
                    //'partials*//***/*//*',
                    'css/png*//***/*//*'
                ]
            }]
        }
    },

});

grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'clean:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concat',
    'usemin'

]);
```

};

Answer (score 0):

In your `copy:dist` setup you have your `cwd` set to the same as your destination directory.

Change to:

```
cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
```

But the problem is then that you defined:

```
var projectConfig = {
    app: ['./'],
    dist: 'dist'
};
```

where I would have expected to see `app` to have a value other than `['./']` but rather something like `'app'`. If you make the first change I suggest without altering the directory structure you'll end up with `app` as an array of locations of length one being your project root including `dist` attempting to be copied into `dist`, unless I'm missing something else about your structure.

Comment: Hi Jason, I changed the copy:dist function to use the main app folder. I still get the same issue. I tried moving the file up one level and I get the same issue as well. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: I had to guess at your directory structure, can you summarize where you have your files?

Comment: Looks like I'll need to customise the tasks. All good. I'll be sure to post my code when I'm done.